# Error in Properties of .net Project & Designer file is locked

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, projects-and-solutions

Designer file is locked and when go to project properties it gives this error.

**An error occurred trying to load the project properties window.  Close the window and try again. The CurrentContext property of the LicenseManager is currently locked and cannot be changed.**

.net framework 3.5
VS 2008

Comment: I'm having the exact same exception but using .net 4.0 and VS2010 with devexpress components. Using VS.net safemode I can change the project properties file but the designer is still borked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See following

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/b3bf3b31-85ac-4073-be2b-2f061b240e63

Answer (score 6):

Just a random suggestion:

Close VS, then try deleting any .suo or .csproj.user files. These store per user settings like which files you have open etc, and can sometimes get corrupted. (maybe back them up first just in case)

Comment: Just ran into this.  Renaming the .suo and .user files did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the resources that you use in your project are compiled with different versions of
the .net framework.

Right click on your project, choose properties and change Target framework to the framework 
that the resources are compiled with, or remove those resources and continue.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Simon.. I was getting this error and could not resolve this.. I removed all unused references from mysoftware properties under project menu and then i removed the unused data base. it resolved my problem. i m sure it will work for you.

Sometimes some corrupted files causes this problem although you never applied and sort of licensing to your software.

njoy..

SandeepV

Adobe Certified Expert

Microsoft Certified IT Professional

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when the designer codes hits a while true Application.DoEvents infinite loop in a button/dropdown/control constructor.

You can see VS.net taking up one cpu core completely and you can debug this pretty easily with another Visual Studio instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error on opening a form design ( not the xml type), you can close the form, open project property, select build tab, click on .net framework version and you can choose the same version again,
close the project property, open th eform again. that's how I got rid of the error,
closing visual studio and re-opening the project did not help me

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem in vs devexpress report
I just clicked on Build>Rebuild solution and the issue was solved